# combine two string arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a simple way (can be with jQuery) to combine two string arrays:

```
var a = ["a", "s", "d"];
var b = ["q", "w", "e"];
```

to produce:

```
var c = ["a q", "s w", "d e"];
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: And you didn't try [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: are the arrays always of equal length?

Comment: var a = ["a", "s", "d","w"];
    var b = ["q", "w", "e"];
    
    var possibility1 = a.map(function(item, i) {
      return item + ' ' + b[i]
    })
    alert(possibility1);
    var possibility2=a.concat(b); 
    alert(possibility2);

if there are two same thing use map if u want for one time,if y want for two time than use concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.map((e, i) => e + ' ' + b[i])
```

Tushar has got it right and probably the best and most efficient way

Answer (score 1):

Try this (check the output in the console):

```js
var a = ["a", "s", "d"]; //add or remove items
var b = ["q", "w", "e"]; //add or remove items

if(a.length>b.length) {
  var biggest = a.slice();
  var smallest = b.slice();
} else {
  var biggest = b.slice();
  var smallest = a.slice();
}

var c = biggest.map(function(num, i) {
  if(i < smallest.length) return num + " " + smallest[i];
  return num;
});

console.log(c);

//CHECK OUTPUT IN CONSOLE
```

This allows for the arrays to be different in size, and still produce same result. Otherwise just map on `a` do the conditional on `b`

Here is a [**Live Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/y43n37op/).

Answer (score 0):

You either use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var a = ["a", "s", "d"];
var b = ["q", "w", "e"];

var c = a.map(function(item, i) {
  return item + ' ' + b[i]
})
```

or [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var c = a.reduce(function(prev, item, i) {
  return prev.concat(item + ' ' + b[i])
}, [])
```

Whatever you like more. If you are in ES2015 friendly world then using arrow functions make it even nicer:

```
// map
var c = a.map((item, i) => item + ' ' + b[i])

// reduce
var c = a.reduce((prev, item, i) => prev.concat(item + ' ' + b[i]), [])
```

Comment: `a.map((e, i) => e + ' ' + b[i])`

Answer (score 0):

If the array length is equal for `a and b` then you can try this.

```
var a = ["a", "s", "d"];
var b = ["q", "w", "e"];
var c = [];
for (var i=0;i<a.length; i++) {
    val = a[i] + " " + b[i];
    c.push(val)
}
console.log(c)
```